# Is there a way to set up generator for QT Cmake project for parallel compiling?

Tags: qt, makefile, cmake

I'm using Windows and Qt Creator and CMake.

I have been able to get my project to build using the default generator that Qt uses: nmake Makefiles.  Unfortunately, the build only uses one core.  Looking at the makefile that's generated, it has a variable called $MAKEFLAGS, but I don't know how to alter that.  I tried adding: -DMAKEFLAGS=-j on the cmake command under the Qt Creator build settings, but CMake doesn't understand that.

One other aspect I don't understand is that I can't go to the Qt CMake build directory and run the same command.  The command Qt Creator tells me it's using is:

cmake.exe --build . --target all

but when I do this within the cmd window it seems to tell me it can't find nmake:

C:\Projects\Git\build-AO3D-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Default>cmake --build . --target all
The system cannot find the file specified
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "all"

I searched my filesystem to find nmake and it's not found, but somehow Qt Creator can run this same build command in this same folder.

So to sum up: how can I use multiple cores?  Is there a better generator for me to use?  Why can't I build using the build command that Qt claims it's using on the command line?

Comment: It should be present in QT creator installation directory, did you check it?

Comment: nmake isn't part of Qt but part of MSVC/visual studio. Build from a VS2015 command prompt or source vcvarsall.bat. What you want to call is jom.exe though, it comes with creator and is an nmake drop-in replacement that does parallel builds. Also have a look at ninja.

Comment: Thanks - I will definitely make it my goal to switch to jom nmake.

Comment: I realize now that I previously tried 'nmake jom'  but ran across errors when I did that.  I'll try a bit more, but will likely ask a separate question for the 'nmake makefiles jom' generator errors I see.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Projects/Git/build-AO3D-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Default/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

  

  Run Build Command:"jom" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_f1503\fast"

  

  Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "jom" "/NOLOGO"
  "cmTC_f1503\fast"

Comment: I was able to get past the errors I originally had with with JOM and it worked fine for parallel builds.  I finally ended up using CodeBlocks NMake Makefiles, which is the best of both worlds.  It allowed me to have parallel builds, but it also did a better job than 'NMake Makefiles JOM' because Qt Creator is able to parse the CMake project (e.g. show all subfolders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NMake simply doesn't support parallel jobs. Use [jom](https://wiki.qt.io/Jom) and respective CMake generator.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer.  The other minor question re: the location of nmake was answered in the comments section of my question.